# Command Line FuseIT in a wine bottle?

Tags: fuseit

I know this is pretty obscure, but has anyone been successful running the command line FuseIT tool in a Wine bottle? I'm trying to run it on my Mac without needing a VM.

Alternatively, if you've found a way to automatically download backup files natively on a Mac, I'd love to know.

Comment: I've been considering porting the FuseIT tooling to .NET Core. Would that make it easier for you to run on a Mac?

Comment: Thanks - I have to admit though that I don’t know enough about it those technologies to give an intelligent answer. Apologies.